# jquery Ajax Request SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, ajax, asmx

I am trying to return an array of products using a get request. The response returns XML with a 200 request.

Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<product> GetAllProducts()
{
    using (SchulteDesignYourOwnEntities db = new SchulteDesignYourOwnEntities())
    {
        return db.products.ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.organizeliving.com/designwebservice.asmx/GetAllProducts',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("Result: " + result.length);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log("Status: " + xhr.status);
                        console.log("Message: " + thrownError);
                    }
                });


            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: check whether any of the string properties in returned product list contains `<` character

Comment: It does. My problem appears that I cannot return json from my .asmx web service. My response is Soap/ XML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have the `dataType` as `'json'`.  jQuery will automatically try to parse JSON from the response.  If it cannot, it considers it an error.

XML is not valid JSON (it will really hate the opening `<`).  You can either change the `dataType` to `'xml'` (or nothing) or actually emit pure JSON from the server instead.

Comment: It succeeds, however, my method says result is undefined. It appears it never parses the data.

Comment: It says undefined because `result` is a JSON object, not a string. Either use `$.param(result).length` or use your own JSON serialiser.