# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Ajax call web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a problem with web service web call by js and I need your help.
Thanks

My code service :

```
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Ajax call service :

```
function callServices() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    };
```

My problem when I pressed F12 to show:
[Click to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFdVG.png)

Comment: what is the response you're seeing in Network Tab in inspector? more precisely what this file is outputting? `WebService.asmx/HelloWorld`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726646/jquery-ajax-request-syntaxerror-unexpected-token